# Files gone after disk utility repair tool. however, space on disk remains

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk

I stupidly repaired my external hard disk without backing it up via mavericks's disk utility repair option.

After the repair, all my folders disappeared but at the same time I noticed that the disk space still remained the same. Is there anyway to get these files back? My thesis is on it.

[image: See capacity and number of files]

when running disk repair again, it managed to find the files but at the same time it doesnt restore it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the Finder to show invisible files. The following Applescript will toggle that on/off.

The report says files were moved to a folder called "." which will be invisible. If you're lucky they may be in there... otherwise it's time for [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com) or Data Recovery [Data Recovery](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) [neither of which are free]

The next things to do will be, in order...

1. Invest in a backup strategy; Time Machine, Backblaze etc & use it.
2. Throw that drive out & use an HFS+ formatted drive, with Journalling - because Mac's support for NTFS is not great.. & by default can't write or repair NTFS, so you either have Paragon or similar or you enabled it via Terminal.

Toggle Invisibles Applescript [copy/paste to Applescript Editor, save as Application]

```
        --Toggle Invisibles
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            -- on launch check invis files state, if invis, switch to vis
            set onOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
            if onOff = "NO" or onOff = "OFF" then
                my showAllFiles()
            else
                my hideAllFiles()
            end if
            my testFinderRunning()
        end try
    end tell

    --Finder Visible & relaunch sub-routine
    on showAllFiles()
        do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON"
        tell application "Finder" to quit
        delay 3
        try
            tell application "Finder" to activate
        end try
    end showAllFiles

    on hideAllFiles()
        --try
        set onOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
        do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF" --OnOffCommand
        tell application "Finder" to quit
        delay 3
        try
            tell application "Finder" to activate
        end try
    end hideAllFiles

    on testFinderRunning()
        set test to 0
        --try
        repeat while test = 0
            log test
            tell application "System Events" to set test to count (every process whose name is "Finder")
            delay 2
            --we do this even if active because it doesn't naturally come to front
            try
                tell application "Finder" to activate
            end try
            if (test > 0) then exit repeat
        end repeat
    end testFinderRunning
```